# Swift: How to remove item from a Set of custom objects based on custom condition (higher order function)

Tags: ios, swift, set

Let's assume I have a `Set` of Custom objects (i.e. Person), something like this:

```
struct Person: Hashable {
let name: String
let age: Int
}

let persons: Set<Person> = [Person(name: "Willy", age: 25), Person(name: "Jenny", age: 22)]
```

If I was to remove all items that have a specific name, I cannot find a `Set` method for this case. 
In `Array` there is such a method called:

```
@inlinable public mutating func removeAll(where shouldBeRemoved: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows
```

But for some reason I cannot find an equivalent in `Set`.

So my solution was to perform a quick conversion for the removing procees something like this:

```
var arr = Array(persons)

arr.removeAll {
    $0.name == "Willy"
}

persons = Set(arr)
```

Is there any direct solution In `Set` rather than using `Array` as a middle-man?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set = set.filter { $0.value != 1 }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a higher order filter to create a new set that excludes objects with the name property "Willy":

```
let persons: Set<Person> = [
   Person(name: "Willy", age: 25),
   Person(name: "Jenny", age: 22)
]

let set = persons.filter{$0.name != "Willy"}
```

Comment: can you please add some comments to your answer to make it more helpful to others?

Comment: I'm not sure what's unclear. The OP said he wanted to "remove all items that have a specific name" from a set without "using Array as a middle-man". I copied  his original set example and used filter to filter out the object that had a specific name, in this case, "Willy". I'll add comments to clarify .

Comment: Thank you. While the code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how the code answers the question improves its long-term value. I have refactored your answer for readability.

Comment: Thanks for editing it. If my code answers the question can you please also mark my answer as correct.

Comment: The user who posted the question decides which answer they consider most helpful and therefore marked as "accepted". Note that if your answer is not "accepted", it does not mean that it is incorrect.